# Passing the object of FileUpload success callback to Controller Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

### **JSON String**

> [{"Program":"eBay
>   US","Date":"/Date(1384108200000)/","TimePlus":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Campaign":"cwsi12","Clicks":0,"EPC":3.3799,"Earnings":6.7599,"CampaignID":"5337412363","Impression":"0","Status":"Duplicate
>   in Database"},{"Program":"eBay
>   US","Date":"/Date(1384108200000)/","TimePlus":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Campaign":"cwsi12","Clicks":0,"EPC":3.3799,"Earnings":6.7599,"CampaignID":"5337412363","Impression":"0","Status":"Duplicate
>   in Database"},{"Program":"eBay
>   US","Date":"/Date(1384108200000)/","TimePlus":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Campaign":"cwsi12","Clicks":0,"EPC":3.3799,"Earnings":6.7599,"CampaignID":"5337412363","Impression":"0","Status":"Duplicate
>   in Database"},{"Program":"eBay
>   US","Date":"/Date(1384108200000)/","TimePlus":"/Date(-62135596800000)/","Campaign":"cwsi12","Clicks":0,"EPC":3.3799,"Earnings":6.7599,"CampaignID":"5337412363","Impression":"0","Status":"Duplicate
>   in Database"}]

### **View Model**

```
public class EbayEarnings_Temp
{
    public String Program { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimePlus { get; set; }
    public String Campaign { get; set; }
    public int Clicks { get; set; }
    public decimal EPC { get; set; }
    public decimal Earnings { get; set; }
    public String CampaignID { get; set; }
    public String Impression { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

var serializer = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(EbayEarnings_Temp));
var c = (EbayEarnings_Temp)serializer.ReadObject(jsonString);
```

I am getting this error

### **Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message is json object not list. You must have integrated serializer or serialize json object in action manually.
I think it must look like this:

```
public ActionResult action(Object Message)
{    
    // deserialise if Object Message is a string
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var c = serializer.Deserialize<YourClass>(Message);

    // deserialise if Object Message is a JsonObject
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(YourClass));
    var c = (YourClass)serializer.ReadObject(Message);

    return PartialView(Message);
}
```

**or another solution:**

I use library [Newtonsoft.Json](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/). If you're going to use it in your case it would look like:

```
...    
MyClass m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(message.ToString());
var status = m.Status; //...and so on
```

Comment: Lookup JavaScriptSerializer for deserializing string or DataContractJsonSerializer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908232.aspx) if its Json object. I've updated @Maksim Pavlov's answer with deserialization options.